# Why my frame index is full of 0 when I make it to copy another frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got such a code:

```
df_submission_gb = pd.DataFrame({'skilled': (y_pred_gb>0.5).astype(int)},
index=df_test.index)
df_submission_gb.to_csv('submission_gb_roles.csv')
df_submission_gb.tail()
```

It takes data from `array y_pred_gb` and puts it to frame `df_submission_gb` with indexes from `df_test`

But output ID field is just zeroes:

[image]

But df_test have ID field:

[image]

And is is set is index on open:

```
df_test = pd.read_csv("data/test_extended", index_col="id").drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0"])
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I see is that you have duplicate values in the column id. Try doing `data_frame_name['id'].value_counts()` to check. You will have to do this before making id as index